Next.js and Auth.js: signin link no longer works after signout
My app uses next.js 14.2.3 and auth.js 5.0.0-beta.19.
Google signin form
import {signIn} from '@/auth';

export default function GoogleSigninForm() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        'use server';
        await signIn('google');
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Continue with Google</button>
    </form>
  );
}

Signout form:
import {signOut} from '@/auth';

export default function SignOutForm() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        'use server';
        await signOut();
      }}
    >
      <button type="submit">Sign Out</button>
    </form>
  );
}

auth.config.ts:
import type {NextAuthConfig} from 'next-auth';

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin'
  },

  callbacks: {
    // server
    authorized({auth, request: {nextUrl}}) {
      const pathname = nextUrl?.pathname;

      // If user is not logged in, authorize access if accessing /signin or /signup, otherwise redirect to /signin
      if (!auth?.user) {
        if (pathname === '/signin' || pathname === '/signup') {
          return true;
        }
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/signin', nextUrl));
      }

      // User is logged in, redirect to / if accessing /signin or /signup, otherwise authorize access
      if (pathname === '/signin' || pathname === '/signup') {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    }
  },

  providers: []
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

When clicking sign out, in Chrome developer tool network tab, you can see localhost fetch:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 303 See Other
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

and address bar will have http://localhost:3000/, and the signin/ page is shown. Now, if you click Continue with Google, the browser just sends the following request:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

and nothing else happens, the browser stays on the signin/ page. Now if you reload the page, everything works fine.
I found a fix, which is changing
await signOut();

to
await signOut({redirectTo: '/signin'});

What is the root cause of this issue, or phenomenon? Is this expected behavior? How to fix it? Is it because the page is not re-hydrated by next.js after signout?
Thanks in advance!
